# Django Adaptor CSV import Date format issues

Tags: django, csv, django-adaptors

I am trying to upload a csv file into a database with a date column using the package Django Adaptor - https://django-adaptors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

My csv file date format is **%d/%m/%Y** and it seem the system only accept a date format **%Y-%m-%d**.

How do I change my csv format to fit the system? Or is there away to change the system to accept my csv file date format? I am using Django 10.1. Thanks in advance!

```
class Transactions(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    description = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2)
    balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2)

class UploadTransactionsModel(CsvDbModel):

    class Meta:
        delimiter = ";"
        dbModel = Transactions
```

settings.py
    DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%d/%m/%Y']

Comment: Are you sure about this? What is the order of your fields in your CSV file?

Comment: ["'10/10/2016,testing,2.1,1752.75' value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format."]

Comment: can you please upload a sample of your CSV file? You have put the delimiter as `;` but it seems it should be `,`

Comment: OMG it worked!! Thanks so much!

Comment: Hi Burhan - sorry it seems I am still haveing the issue. django.core.exceptions.ValidationError: ["'10/10/2016' value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format."] (The previous csv I uploaded worked because I manually change the date format to YYY-MM-DD)